# Does NSStringFromCGPoint return an autoreleased object?

Tags: iphone, memory

Question #1
Will `NSStringFromCGPoint()` return an autorelease object or does the object needs to be released?

Question #2
When you have a property : `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;`
And you set it like so: self.someString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Something"] autorelease];

Is this:

```
[someString release];
someString = nil;
```

equal to

```
self.someString = nil;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I haven't checked that one specifically, but by convention those sorts of functions return autoreleased objects. You might be able to test this yourself by setting up a minimal, non-ARC project and calling `-retainCount` on what you get out of the function, but I'm not sure. (And in general, `retainCount` isn't something you want to use.)
2. Yes. The synthesized setter looks something like:

   ```
   - (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)string
   {
       if (string != someString) {
           [someString release];
       }
       someString = [string retain];
   }
   ```

So, whether you call it explicitly or using the dot notation, the old value gets released (and the underlying ivar gets set to `nil` or whatever you pass in).

Also, I'm not sure if you were just doing it for a random example, but you don't have to wrap a string literal in memory management code to pass it to the property accessor. (That is, `self.someString = @"Something"` is fine.)

Comment: [Never use `retainCount`](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/).  Never.  Ever.  Never ever.  Unicorns will cry, and kitties will be hurt.  Don't do it.

Comment: It was just an example thank you for your clear answer, I accepted it as you can see.

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing there's a better way to see whether the object returned by a function is autoreleased, in case you're ever not sure you want to trust the convention. You could put that function call in its own little autorelease pool, then test the pointer afterward. If it's still around, you got an object you're expected to release... if you crash, the object was autoreleased.

Comment: No, actually you should just look into the memory management guidelines and read what keywords indicate a non-autoreleased object.

Comment: You cannot use `retainCount` to test for `autorelease`.   Nor will @rickster's suggestion work; behavior when messaging a deallocated instance is undefined and memory is not modified on deallocation (as well, some objects are never deallocated).

Answer (score 1):

Does the call include the term "new", "alloc", "copy", or "create"? If not, you're getting back an object that you do not own (you may assume it is either autoreleased or that the reference is owned elsewhere).